# How to handle backend async calls in React?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, server, client

It takes more time from server to calculate and return data, so it is async in backend. It means, as soon as request is send, server will send 202 and client will listen to wamp for 200 or any other response for same request.

api1: client sent request --> server returns 202 --> client waits for wamp 200 response.

I have achieved this, but problem comes when chain of api request is there in place.

Here is scenario:

api1 response is to be fed to api2 and api2 response is to be fed to api3. And all these apis are async at server.

Flow will be like:

client request api1 --> server sends 202 response for api1 --> client waits for 200 wamp response for api1 --> on 200 wamp for api1, client requests api2 --> server sends 202 response api2 --> client waits for 200 wamp response for api2 --> on 200 wamp for api2, client requests api3 --> client waits for 200 wamp response for api3 --> displays data in UI.

I have handled above scenario using actions in saga and slice. But there are many flows like that in my application, and I have to repeat similar logic again and  again. Also, with this, code is not readable.

In sync calls, we have promise, same way, can someone tell, if anything is there to handle above scenario in a more generic way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "client will listen to wamp for 200"? Are you using websockets? Or is it some sort of polling?

Comment: I am using websocket.